# Codesys question about using a Ladder function block into a SFC (doesn't work properly)

Tags: function, instance, block, codesys, sfc

I have a function block made in Ladder which I want to use in SFC, but I can't get it work properly. I hope someone knows the solution here.

This is my devices tree:

[image: DevicesTree]

I have the following function block:

[image: Function block]

And this is my SFC. A variable is declared with the type of the function block:
It's a very simple SFC. In `step0` the `SetGreen` input is set in the `TrafficLight` instance.

[image: SFC]

The `MainTask` calls the SFC to run it each cycle.

[image: MainTask]

Now if I start the program, the function block doesn't work. The `SetGreen` input is set but the SR-flipflop doesn't flip the output to high:

[image: Debug output]

Does someone knows why this doesn't work? Perhaps I also need to call the function block instance somewhere  each cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Although you are setting the internal variable `SetGreen` (which I don't recommend, it's internal for a reason, use an input), I don't see anywhere you calling the Function Block `TrafficLight` that uses taht variable. Unless you call/execute the Function Block, the code inside it **won't be executed**.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I call the function block? I guess it should be somewhere in the SFC POU because that is the owner?

Comment: Yes, you need to call it in the parent (owner). How and when is up to you depending on inmplementation you want. I have little experience with SFC, mainly use ST.